# PHP PSR-4 - Class not found

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, vendor

I've added my namespace with PHP, but can't get it working.

What I am doing wrong with my setup? When I want to call my test-class:

```
https://hilfe.kbs-community.de/index.php?controller=TanoaLife&params=123
```

I get the error message:

> Class 'KWinkel\Helpdesk\Controller\TanoaLife' not found

My setup:

```
index.php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

// autoloader 
$Autoloader = require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$Autoloader->add('KWinkel\\Helpdesk\\', 'app/');

// controller
if ( isset($_GET["controller"]) ) {
    $Controller = $_GET["controller"];
    if ( file_exists("app/Controller/" . $Controller . ".class.php") ) {
        $Class = "KWinkel\Helpdesk\Controller\\" . $Controller;
        new $Class($_GET["params"]);
    } else {
        echo "invalid call #1";
    }
} else {
    echo "invalid call #2";
}

$SysContent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $SysContent;

?>


app/Controller/TanoaLife.class.php
<?php
namespace KWinkel\Helpdesk\Controller;

class TanoaLife extends AbstractController {
    //

    function __construct ($Params) {
        echo "params: " . $Params;
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: Die your classfile where TanoaLife is defined, define the namespace `KWinkel\Helpdesk\Controller`?

Comment: A picture of code is useless, please paste the relevant code into your question.

Comment: Sorry, I've added my code and the paths to the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classfile `TanoaLife.class.php` should look like this:

```
 namespace KWinkel\Helpdesk\Controller;

 class TanoaLife {

 }
```

and should be placed here:

`app/Controller/TanoaLife.class.php`

to work with the Autoloader.

UPDATE: I would prefer to name the classfile `TanoaLife.php` instead of `TanoaLife.class.php` or you have to setup the `autoloader` to include classes with suffix `.class.php`

`$Autoloader->addPsr4('KWinkel\\Helpdesk\\', 'app');`

https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php

Comment: Its already the case, I've added some information to the first post

Comment: Did your autloader now that he has to add .class.php instead of .php to the classname when he try to load it?

Comment: No, I have removed .class from my index.php & from the file paths. It's NOT working anyway..

Comment: Also from you `file_exists()` part?

Comment: Yes (Class 'KWinkel\Helpdesk\Controller\TanoaLife' not found). Do I need more to do than I did in my index.php (Autoloader->add..)?

Comment: Try ` $Autoloader->add('KWinkel\\Helpdesk\\', _ _DIR_ _.'/app/');` removespaces beetween minus. can not write it better

Comment: Try `var_export($Autoloader->getClassMap());` and look if all is correct, FORGET THAT you are not yousing a `classmap` here, sorry, my fault

Comment: Its an empty array Edit4yourEdit: Na okay, I'm really thankful for your help

Comment: Ok, try too use `addPsr4()` instead off `add()`, same args given

Comment: Just did it 3 minutes before, no success

Comment: Ok, maybe add \ before KWinkel on the `$Class = ` line

Comment: currently call " new KWinkel\Helpdesk\Controller\TanoaLife("123"); " in index.php and commented out the $_GET part. Still the same error --- Edit: new \KWinkel\Helpdesk\Controller\TanoaLife("123");  does not work too

Comment: OK, include the classfile direct and test makeing an instance, to be sure that this part is ok.

Comment: OK, so claassfile is ok an includable, the bug must be in the autoloader setup.

Comment: Just to clear that: I have nothing with autoloader in my composer.json, because that did not work too

Comment: MAybe you  have to re-run `dump-autoload` to re-generate the vendor/autoload.php file, more i cant say, everything else seems right, namespace, filename ....

Comment: ran composer dump-autoload .. no success ;(

Comment: lasttry: Test ` $Class = "KWinkel\\Helpdesk\\Controller\\" . $Controller;`

Comment: Currently calling "  new KWinkel\Helpdesk\Controller\TanoaLife('123');  "  without including class. for testing purpose and commented the rest on the bottom out. only WITH including it works, so he does not include properly

Comment: I thing the only thing that helps you now is to add debug_print_backtrace(); on each method in your Composer/ClassLoader  to find the bug.

Comment: From here i cant help any more. But i thing it a little bug ;-) somewhere :)

Comment: You can also try `$Autoloader->findFile($class);` to see if it find the classpath and there you can see if it set up right or not set at all

Comment: I see waht you do, can you tell me where `Bramus` is added to the loader?

Comment: Yes, currently printing all the stuff in LoadClass.php --- take a look there: https://github.com/bramus/router

Comment: Yes, and the question is where is the BRAMUS part added too the autoloader, dint thing in your index.php

Comment: Thats the only thing in my require field: "require": {
        "bramus/router": "~1.0"
    }

Comment: ahh ok, its then added via composer

Comment: Hopefully it is not the issue but change `$Autoloader->add('KWinkel\\Helpdesk\\', 'app/');` to `$Autoloader->add('KWinkel\Helpdesk', 'app/');`

Comment: the problem is inside the findFileWithExtension function inside the ClassLoader.php; take a look at my testing-page --- already changed that back \\ -> \

Comment: Can u var_dump($this); after $logicalPathPsr4  in the findFileWithExtension()

Comment: Do this: `$Autoloader->add('KWinkel\Helpdesk', 'app/');`  or this `$Autoloader->addPsr4('KWinkel\\Helpdesk\\', 'app/');` and test that

Comment: Wrong,  REMOVED       !

Comment: Nope im fullly out,  see ghost around me.  Hope you will fix this, im out.

Comment: I see you got it now ;-))

Comment: Wow... $Autoloader->addPsr4('KWinkel\\Helpdesk\\', 'app');  does work.. I think I will hang myself after this xD

Comment: Have a nice day, :-) you can mark my answer as right, i have updated it

Comment: Thanks a lot! You too!